# Какой шаблон проектирования применить в при подключении API?

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть АПИ сервиса, который предоставляет такие возможности:

- Загрузить каталог товаров (группы, бренды, конкретные товары и т.п.)
- Управление корзиной (добавить, удалить, обновить данные о товаре, управление группированием товаров, сформировать заказ)
- Управление заказом (получить, изменить данные о заказе, поставщике)

Есть класс **Api**, к которому обращается клиентский код. На данный момент написан функционал, который работает с каталогом товаров и класс представляет из себя что-то вроде этого:

```
class Api {
    private $authApi;
    private $logger;
    const URL_API = "www.www.www";

    function __construct()
    {
        global $_AUTH_API;
        $this->authApi = $_AUTH_API;
        $this->logger = new CustomLogs();
    }

    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        /////
    }

    public function getBLABLABLA($id)
    {
        /////
    }

    /////////////// Some functions which get some data from API ///////////

    protected function requestApi($data)
    {
        /////
    }

    protected function sendRequest($data)
    {
        /////
    }

    protected function jsonDecode($json)
    {
        /////
    }
}
```

Пихать все функции с работой АПИ в один класс, думаю плохая идея. Получится слишком много методов, одни из которых тянут данные из каталога, а другие работают с корзиной.

Как организовать код и какой шаблон проектирования подойдет в данной ситуации?

Comment: Организуйте как обычный сайт, просто формат вывода данных будет не HTML, а json. MVC вполне подходит

Comment: У меня cron скрипт обращается к этому классу, чтобы импортировать и обновлять данные о товарах. Речь идёт конкретно о том, как разбить этот класс и как к нему обращаться извне.

Comment: @ilyaplot у меня тоже самое в голове. Пример реализации не помешал бы.

Answer (score 1):

Клиент я обычно делаю так: В базовом классе общие методы (соединение, отправка запроса и получение ответа, авторизация), в отдельных классах описаны методы API. Для каждого метода свой класс. Для похожих методов можно использовать абстракцию для сокращения количества кода

Для примера:

```
class ApiClient 
{
   protected $methods = [
      'getPrice' => GetPrice::class,
      'another' => Another::class,
   ];

   public function sendRequest($method, $params = [])
   {
       .....
       // Отправляем запрос, заворачиваем данные в класс - обработчик
       return $this->processResult($method, $data);
       //В случае ошибки можно вызвать какой-нибудь processError
   }


   protected function processResult($method, $data) 
   {
      return (new $this->methods[$method]())->process($data);
   }
}

interface ApiMethodInterface 
{
    public function process($data);
}

abstract class Method implemends ApiMethodInterface 
{
   // тут пишем общие функции для всех методов API
}

class GetPrice extends Method 
{
    public function process($data)
    {
        // Выполняем какую-то работу с данными
        return ....;
    }
}

class Another extends Method 
{
    public function process($data)
    {
        // Выполняем какую-то работу с данными
        return ....;
    }
}
```

Так же можно в клиенте просто обозначить список команд, а методы, которые они должны обрабатывать прописать в самих командах. Так же, можно предусмотреть разные HTTP методы отправки данных в командах (POST, GET, PUT, etc..). В таком случае команды должны ссылаться на объект, обеспечивающий соединение с API.

Так же можно использовать магические методы. Например, [__call](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

```
public function __call($method, $data)
{
    return (new $this->methods[$method]())->process($data);
}
```

Тогда можно использовать класс ApiClient так: $api->getPrice([1,2,3]) // выполнится process в классе GetPrice

Comment: И сколько это классов должно получиться? Например, если нужные такие методы: getBrands, getProductsByBrand, getGroups, getCategories и ещё куча.

Comment: Сколько методов, столько и классов. https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/tree/master/src/Commands/SystemCommands Вот для примера реализация клиента для Telegram бота.

Comment: Вообще поищите API клиенты на GitHub и посмотрите как они устроены, но прежде убедитесь, что вам будет удобна такая реализация. Т.е. сначала смотрите документацию к проекту